# How can I display 0 or 1 from a json file to html with a green tick (1) or a red cross (0)?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a json file with some data.

```
[ {"id": 1, "name": "xy", "status": 0}
  {"id": 2, "name": "yz", "status": 1}]
```

The third key is a status key, 1 if the item is available, 0 if it's not.

I have a html table, I display the ids, names, and the status from the json file, but i dont want a 0 or 1 in that cell, i would like to show a green tick or a red cross.

I display the table with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("mydata.json", function(data) {
        var radio_data = '';
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            radio_data += '<tr>';
            radio_data += '<td>' + value.state + '</td>';
            radio_data += '<td>' + value.author + '</td>';
            radio_data += '<td>' + value.album + '</td>';
            radio_data += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#mytable').append(radio_data);
    });
});
```

The 0 or 1 value is in the 1. row the "state".

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to display your table?

Comment: `if (object.status === 1) { /* add green image */ } else { /* add red image */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where exactly you're displaying the id, name, and status (based on the code you shared for how you build the table), but if you have the dict you want from that json saved as a variable called object, you can use it to choose a bootstrap glyphicon and put it the table (Note, you'll have to update the header to include a blank `<th><th>` for the column you want to display the icon in):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var icon_html = ''  
    if(object.status == 1){
         icon = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="color:green">'
    }
    else{
       icon = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color:red">' 
    }
    $.post("mydata.json", function(data) {
        var radio_data = '';
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            radio_data += '<tr>';
            radio_data += '<td>' + value.state + '</td>';
            radio_data += '<td>' + value.author + '</td>';
            radio_data += '<td>' + value.album + '</td>';
            radio_data += '<td>' + icon_html + '<td>';
            radio_data += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#mytable').append(radio_data);
     });
```

This also assumes you have Bootstrap in your app, which if you don't I would definitely recommend for this kind of thing, you can use it for free simply by putting the following in the `<head>` section of your html:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If you aren't familiar with bootstrap, it's real straight forward, you can get started here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/

and find all the glyphicons here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#glyphicons

Comment: Thanks for your answer, firstly i dont want to share all the data(no its not a secret :D) and just write 3 (id, name, state) but after i edited the post and shared the complete code. Yes, i use bootstrap of course it helps a lot.
Thank you again for the quick and precise answer.